# Tp4056 lipo Charge module

Tags: tp4056

This is my first post and I am fairly new to the DIY small electrical stuff.

I am trying to power some 12 V strip LED lights using 2x 18650 batteries wired in parallel and a step up converter.

The part I am stuck in is the wiring of the TP4056 charge module. I want to use 2 separate TP4056 charge modules but only 1 power supply. The part I am stuck on is the output from both TP4056 modules that feed the step up converter. Can they just be connected together and is this safe? Attached is a photo of the module being used.

[image]

Comment: You can use one power supply if you connect batteries parallel. You have two tp4056 IC and their outputs will charge your individual batteries. In terms of ground it's ok. But you have to think over how you connect two different voltage level in one point to supply your step up converter.

Comment: If your batteries are in parallel, you can charge them with one charger module. Why do you want to charge a single battery pack with two chargers? Are you even sure you can parallel two chargers and it will work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply’s. Would the tp4056 be suitable to charge 2 18650 cells? I thought it was single cell only

Comment: 2 cells in parallel (2P) is OK with a tp4056, though they will take longer to charge.. (2cells in series is not). Charge (or discharge) them both to the same voltage before paralleling them.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. 
Also do you know if a 12v photo cell switch wired in before the led lights would work? Instead of using a rocker switch to operate them